# How to pass the size of an allocatable user-defined (derived-type, data structure) variable to a subroutine in fortran?

Tags: data-structures, fortran, user-defined-types, derived-types, allocatable-array

I want to create a [derived-type variable](http://www.star.le.ac.uk/~cgp/f90course/f90.html#tth_sEc8) (a.k.a. structure or user-defined variable), calculate it in one subroutine and use it in another subroutine.  Both components of the structure are allocatable arrays.  I want to know how to tell the subroutines the size of those arrays.  The only way I know how to do that with a derived-type is when allocating, but I can only allocate it once.  The non-derived-type allocatable arrays get declared as a certain size at the beginning of the subroutine and in the interface:

```
double precision, intent(in) :: anotherINP(n,m)
```

But how do I do that for the derived-type arrays?

Further details in case they are useful:
I do have a module:

```
module my_type_module
 type :: MyDataType
 logical, allocatable :: horizjump(:,:)
 integer, allocatable :: value(:,:)
end type
end module
```

and both the main code and the subroutines use it and define my variable using the new type:

```
use my_type_module
TYPE(MyDataType) :: HkeStruct
```

I also have an interface that I put at the beginning of my main code:

```
interface
 subroutine CalcHKE(HkeStruct, n, m, anotherINP)
  use my_type_module
  integer, intent(in):: n,m
  double precision, intent(in) :: anotherINP(n,m)
  TYPE(myDataType), intent(out) :: HkeStruct
end subroutine CalcHKE
subroutine UseHKE(HkeStruct, n,m, Outvars)
  use my_type_module
  integer, intent(in) :: n,m
  double precision, intent(out) :: Outvars
  TYPE(myDataType), intent(in)  :: HkeStruct
end subroutine UseHKE
end interface
```

I tried allocating the components of the structure variable in the main code

```
allocate HkeStruct%horizjump(n,m), HkeStruct%value(n,m)
```

but then ran into trouble when I ran my code with large values n and m when it was writing into that variable (invalid write, address is on stack 1).  So I tried allocating it in the subroutine that creates it, which then caused an invalid read when the other subroutine tried to read it.  (Though both those problems are only evident with large systems and by using valgrind.)

I can get the code to run by passing the components of the structure variable to the second subroutine as regular variables, rather than passing the full structure.  "But it should be able to work with a structure variable!!"

Comment: *then ran into trouble when I ran my code with large values n and m*  You're going to have to show the code, and the exact error messages reported, to get any useful answers or suggestions.  While I'm carping -- in Fortran arrays 'know' their own sizes, and there are intrinsic routines such as `size` and `shape` to figure them out.  If a subroutine needs to know the sizes of arrays passed to it (and subroutines rarely do need to know) they can figure them out.

Comment: Further, programmer-written interfaces such as you show in your question, are rarely necessary when you write modern Fortran with modules and such like.  It's not clear to me what you think you need them for.

Comment: The interfaces are especially not necessary when modules are used. And you seem to use modules.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers...I hear that the answer to my question is that I don't need to tell the subroutine the size of my allocatable derived-type data structure, so something else must be wrong.  I'll edit my question to show the code and the errors I'm getting.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the size:

```
n = size(HkeStruct%horizjump, dim=1)
m = size(HkeStruct%horizjump, dim=2)
```

This works for allocatable arrays passed with assumed shape or in derived types.

The errors you have can be related to the allocation mode of your compiler. Have a look a http://jblevins.org/log/segfault or http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/memory_test/memory_test.html for instance.